# DNS and Wildcard CNAME

Tags: domains, dns, subdomain, cname

Whenever I attempt to make a CNAME record for my domain I get two errors:

> - You can't mix CNAME/MX records together using the same hostname.
> - Domain root's cannot be CNAME's, however you can web-forward this record to `www.example.com` instead for the same effect.

This is how I want it to appear. The last record.

[image: screenshot of problems with cname records]

Question(s):

*I've read it's possible so why can't I make it work?*

Comment: Did you check that your host even allows wildcard DNS? It's not necessarily standard. (Also donated to be a premium member of what? You dropped that comment without explanation.)

Comment: Sorry haha, http://freedns.afraid.org/premium/
They apparently support it.

Comment: Related: http://serverfault.com/questions/44618/is-a-wildcard-cname-dns-record-valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Cloudflare, it's free (upgradeable to premium) and also has caching and DoS protection, as well as hiding your IP addresses. I know for a fact that they support wildcard CNAMEs, like so: http://dev.ionfish.org/temp/cfwildcard.jpg (This is supported on the free version).

Comment: "The requested URL /temp/cfwildcard.jpg was not found on this server." :-(

Comment: I'm sorry, it was temporary, and after the post was resolved I removed it. It was just like this: `CNAME: * (wildcard) >> domain.com (edit, delete)`

Comment: Can you post a screenshot again? I can't seem to get it right. Cloudflare keeps saying `Invalid host value`.